# Changing Scanner's input after hasNext() returned false

Tags: java

I'm using my custom InputStream for Scanner and want to change it. But after first reading and changing data in the InputStream it stops.

Can I modify my code for the second reading? Which way?

*Upd* I use this code with other programs and redirect their standard input to mine. So I need to change System.in and cannot recreate Scanner.

Here are my classes:

```java
class CRStream extends InputStream {
  private ByteArrayInputStream in;
  public synchronized int read() throws IOException {
     int x = in.read();
    return x;
  }
  public synchronized int read(byte[] bytes, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    return in.read(bytes, off, 1);
  }
  public void set(String utf8str) throws IOException{
     try{
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(utf8str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){}
  }
}
```

and example of using

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         CRStream in = new CRStream();
         System.setIn(in);
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         //Everything is OK
         in.set("Word1 Ok Word2 Ok");
         while (scanner.hasNext()){
             System.out.println(scanner.next());
         }
         //Does not work... Prints nothing
         in.set("WORD3 Ok WORD4 Ok");
         while (scanner.hasNext()){
             System.out.println(scanner.next());
         }
    }
}
```

This is a second example

A simple Client program

```java
class ClientProgram {
    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(in.next());
    }
}
```

I test it with code

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         CRStream in = new CRStream();
         System.setIn(in);
         in.set("Test1");
         ClientProgram.main(new String[0]);
         in.set("Test2");
         ClientProgram.main(new String[0]);

    }
}
```

And it falls with `NoSuchElementException` on second test.

Comment: What's the purpose of redirecting `System.in`?  Why not just wrap your `Scanner` directly around `in`?

Comment: It the real project I work with other programs which use Scanner from System.in. So I redirect their standart input to mine.

Comment: It's common to use a `Scanner` with `System.in`, but it's not an absolute requirement, You can read _any_ `InputStream` with a `Scanner`

Comment: All programs I am working with read data by `Scanner` from `System.in`. My purpose is to give  them my own input. Everything works fine, then the other code create Scanner in a function. So I can call it several times and give it new `InputStream`. But if that code create static Scanner variable, it does not work. In this case scanner  is created only once. So the question is "Can we continue use scanner with the same `InputStream` after `hasNext()` returned `false`?

Comment: The issue is your input stream doesn't follow protocol by allowing to set data to it after it has been read entirely. You cannot return -1 on a read once, then something valid later and expect client classes to be fine with it.

Comment: Thank you. And what is workaround? I added another example into the question.Is in possible to reinitialize static Scanner with new data?

Comment: Please never say "I got an exception" on stackoverlow, without giving the exact error message you received (if it's not in English you can also give a translation for it if you want)

Answer (score 0):

Just curious why you're jumping through so many hoops when a scanner can read from a string directly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner("Word1 Ok Word2 Ok");
     while (scanner.hasNext()){
         System.out.println(scanner.next());
     }

     scanner = new Scanner("WORD3 Ok WORD4 Ok");
     while (scanner.hasNext()){
         System.out.println(scanner.next());
     }
```

If you want the Ok to be delimiters you can call `useDelimiter(" Ok ")` on your scanner

As to the actual problem, I suspect that internally scanner might be buffering your input stream and not realise you've pulled a switcheroo on it; perhaps make a new scanner anyway or reset() your crinputstream. There is also no need to replace system inputstream with yours then connect scanner to system in; scanner can read from your input stream without going via system.in

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot recreate Scanner in my code.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I use this code with other programs and redirect their standart input to mine. So I need to change System.in and cannot recreate Scanner.

Comment: You keep saying that same thing but it doesn't really make sense to me. You're overwriting system.in with your own thing so how is that even capable of reading another program's output to system.in? If you can't make a new scanner, reset it after you put new data in the crstream. Also check that your crstream works to see the new data (use it directly and check it works for read() set read() - does it give you what you expect?) if crstream isn't even used in your app please give us an actual example of real life failing code, not this hard to understand fake version?

Comment: I added the second example to the question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing a dodgy new `InputStream`, you should probably wrap around all the inputs you get and just return the strings being parsed. That way, your wrapper class can maintain the `Scanner` it uses depending on what it's reading at the moment.

```
class TokenProvider {
    Queue<Scanner> readFrom = new Deque<Scanner>();
    Scanner currentScanner;

    public void addSource(String string) {
        readFrom.add(new Scanner(string));
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
        nextScanner();
        return currentScanner != null && currentScanner.hasNext();        
    }
    public String next() {
        return currentScanner.next();
    }
    private void nextScanner() {
        while (currentScanner == null || !currentScanner.hasNext()) {
            if (readFrom.isEmpty()) break;
            currentScanner = readFrom.poll();
        }
    }
}
```

Now your driver code looks like this

```
 TokenProvider in = new TokenProvider();
 in.addSource("Word1 Ok Word2 Ok");
 while (in.hasNext()){
     System.out.println(in.next());
 }
 // all data has been iterated, but we can add more now
 in.addSource("WORD3 Ok WORD4 Ok");
 while (in.hasNext()){
     System.out.println(in.next());
 }
```

Comment: I explained poorly at the beginning... Please, look at the second example, I added to the question. It seems to me I cannot wrap client's Scanner, because I know just nothing about it, only that it exists and reads from System.in. Nothing more.

Comment: @VladimirIlyin I don't see how your second example wouldn't work with my code if you change `set` to `addSource`.

Comment: It's not very clear for me. Do you offer me to replace `Scanner` class to your `TokenProvider` in Client class or what? It's possible, I think, but this way I need to add all public Scanner's methods to the TokenProvider such as `nextInt()` etc.

Comment: @VladimirIlyin yeah. My guess is it won't be too many methods that are actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner maintains internal state, sets a flag "sourceClosed=true" once current source runs out. Any future access to Scanner will be rejected since Scanner thinks it's empty despite changing the source stream, as the flag  does not roll back. I don't see a way to circumvent this without a customised scanner implementation. Rather than going into that rabbit-hole, try to use a new Scanner for each read if possible.

In the second client, don't maintain a static Scanner, instead

```
class ClientProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(in.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine, if recreate scanner. But I don't manage client programs, so some of them with absolutelly valid `static Scanner` break my test code.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have clients reading from stdin with Scanners, and you want to control their input via an InputStream?

Comment: Yes... I want control their input. And everything is fine, when they create scanners in a function. But there is no idea how to control static scanners

Comment: I don't think thats possible. Is it possible to initialize stream with all required values instead if trying to add on later? Also, if the client class is loaded before you replace System.in, the scanner would be attached to stdin.

Comment: I load the Client class after replacing `System.in`. And if I  add to the stram all required values at the beginning, I'll break the first example with `hasNext()`, it will read all the data in the first loop.